# USB Logitech gaming controller doesn't get recognized

Tags: usb

I have an offline Mint desktop that has not been connected to the Internet for some time; around the order of a year. So it is not updating for sure. Just got two USB Logitech gaming controllers, they worked out of the box just by plugging them in. And then while using them one suddenly stopped working, and then the second one went shortly afterwards. The USB mouse and keyboard continues to work.

Changing ports and rebooting has done nothing. I have never figured out how you are supposed to manage your devices and drivers on Linux; so I do not even know where to start.

---

I booted up the computer, and plugged in the controller once.

Running `lsusb-t` returned an added Human Interface Device labeled": `Bus 2 Port 2 Dev 0`
And `dmesg|tail -n 20` showed a few things that looked potentially wrong. It talked about the Logitech dual-shock whatever at length, it seems to be showing it being added multiple times. It was taking like: `yadyadayada pci0000,00:0000/yadayada/input13`
`... input0`
`... input14`
`... input0`
A bunch of the exact same lines all with pci followed by a bunch of 0s and the finally input(NUMBER). Does that make sense? The 0s looked to me like they should of been some actual number instead of some sort of null id. And I am not sure why it would show the same basic line over and over again.

Comment: Use the command `lsusb -t` with the controller *unplugged* and *plugged*. If there is a difference it means that at least the hardware level is fine.

Comment: You can also run `dmesg|tail -n 20` after connecting a controller to see what the kernel tried to do (if anything).

Comment: Ran those commands. If you need more specific results let me know.